# Blinking hover in gallery

Tags: html, css, hover, frontend

I have a problem with blinking hover in gallery (html+css). I can't find solution. Can anyone help me fix it?

[Code on jsfiddle.com](http://jsfiddle.net/1nfetLt1/)

```
HTML:
 <div id="gallery">
            <div class="col-sm-6 photo-1">
                <div class="transparent-gallery">
                    <h3>Photo Caption</h3>
                    <p>Donec sodales semper porttitor.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>

CSS: 
            #gallery .photo-1{
            background-image:url(http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130326013809/camp-dublin-roleplay/images/e/ec/Camden-town.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            height:300px;
        }

        .transparent-gallery{
            background: rgba(36, 43, 46, 0.8);
            background-size: cover;
            height:300px;
            width:100%;
            position:absolute;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .transparent-gallery h3, .transparent-gallery p{
            visibility:hidden;
        }

        .transparent-gallery:hover h3, .transparent-gallery:hover p{
            visibility:inherit;
        }

        .transparent-gallery:hover{
            background: rgba(36, 43, 46, 0.95);
            height:110px;
            top:200px;
        }
```

I'm beginner and this code certainly could be better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These attributes should be set like this instead

```
#gallery:hover .transparent-gallery h3, #gallery:hover .transparent-gallery p{
    visibility:inherit;
}

#gallery:hover .transparent-gallery{
    background: rgba(36, 43, 46, 0.95);
    height:110px;
    top:200px;
}
```

**[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/1nfetLt1/1/)**

> This way, basically we are telling the code to do this:
>
> **When** `#gallery:hover` **Show this =>** `.transparent-gallery`

Comment: You're welcome @adfgvx . If you have some time please consider marking my answer as correct =)